# Applying Extension Methods to an Interface. Shopping Cart Example

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The ShoppinCart model:

```
            using System.Collections;
            using System.Collections.Generic;

            namespace LanguageFeatures.Models {

                public class ShoppingCart : IEnumerable<Product> {

                    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

                    public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() {
                        return Products.GetEnumerator();
                    }

                    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
                        return GetEnumerator();
                    }
                }
            }
```

My book is using this code to explain extension methods. I'm finding the exact meaning of:

```
public class ShoppingCart : IEnumerable<Product>
```

is not really explained. Does that mean the ShoppingCart model is going to be derived from the Product model or is there more to it than that? I understand that IEnumerable pertains to iterations over an object and that those iterations are facilitated somehow by GetEnumerator. It is not really explained at all what the purpose of:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
                        return GetEnumerator();
                    }
```

is or why that has to be there as well. What is it doing? All of this code seems to have a lot to do with the extension method here which is declared in MyExtensionMethods model:

```
    public static decimal TotalPrices(this IEnumerable<Product> productEnum) {
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach (Product prod in productEnum) {
            total += prod.Price;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

which is used to get a total price for all the items in the cart. The extension method itself I feel like I understand. The code I am taking from Pro ASP .NET MVC5 Chapter 4 by Adam Feeman.

In the controller the extension method and shopping cart are put to use:

```
public ViewResult UseExtensionEnumerable() {

        IEnumerable<Product> products = new ShoppingCart {
            Products = new List<Product> {
                new Product {Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M},
                new Product {Name = "Lifejacket", Price = 48.95M},
                new Product {Name = "Soccer ball", Price = 19.50M},
                new Product {Name = "Corner flag", Price = 34.95M}
            }
        };

        // create and populate an array of Product objects
        Product[] productArray = {
            new Product {Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M},
            new Product {Name = "Lifejacket", Price = 48.95M},
            new Product {Name = "Soccer ball", Price = 19.50M},
            new Product {Name = "Corner flag", Price = 34.95M}
        };

        // get the total value of the products in the cart
        decimal cartTotal = products.TotalPrices();
        decimal arrayTotal = products.TotalPrices();

        return View("Result",
            (object)String.Format("Cart Total: {0}, Array Total: {1}",
                cartTotal, arrayTotal));
    }
```

Thank you for posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there are two `GetEnumerator` methods in this code is because `IEnumerable<T>` is itself implementing the `IEnumerable` interface (notice how this version lacks the generic type). Thus, you must implement both version of the method to implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Since both methods have the same signature, you have to implement one of the interfaces explicitly. This means that the only way to call this method is through an explicit instance of said interface. In this case, the developer chose to implement `IEnumerable` explicitly and `IEnumerable<T>` implicitly. Finally, since `Enumerable.GetEnumerator()` simply returns `GetEnumerator()` without first casting the this instance explicitely to an `IEnumerable` instance, you end up calling the `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` method which is defined implicitly just a few lines above. This is basically a method overload like any others.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying. About the ": IEnumerable" I think that means something like our class is going to be implementing IEnumerable<Product>?

Comment: Exactly. When defining a class, the part after the colon is the list of interfaces (and maybe one base class) that this class implements.